# Count number of posts from a ListView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I would like to count the number of "todo" in my **ListView**

**views.py**

```
class DashboardListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Links
    template_name = 'dashboard/home.html'
    context_object_name ='links_list'
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['dashboard_list']= Dashboard.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)[:15]
        context['todo_list']= Todo.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).order_by('-pk')[:15]
        context['PasswordUsername_list']= PasswordUsername.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return context
```

And render it with {{c_count}} in my template but was unable to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably will render the list as well, using the [**`length`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#length) is probably the fastest way to do this, since it will fetch the objects, and calculate the length, so we can render this like:

```
{{ todo_list|length }}
```

If you are only interested in the length itself, and not in the objects of a `todo_list`, we can call `.count()` on the `QuerySet`, but this also has an extra disadvantage that it will only work for `QuerySet`s (or classes that have a `.count()` method):

```
<!-- only interested in the count, not in the objects -->
{{ todo_list.count }}
```

Comment: Thanks, 
I would like to render the number only for the **complete** todo, I have already a boelian in the models.py, How can I do that ?

Comment: @GaëtanGR: then you should do a proper `.filter(..)` on the `QuerySet`, something like `Todo.objects.filter(status='done')`, although that depends of course on the model itself.